# Financial / Banking Words

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, hypernyms

I'm putting together a loan application form for a bank. Part of the information that needs to be collected from loan applicants are their:

- Mortgages
- Credit cards
- Loans
- Overdrafts

What is a collective term for the above? The best I can think of is *financial liabilities*, but I feel it may be too overreaching (there are other kinds of financial liabilities that are not "loan" in nature, like child support).

Also, what is a collective term for *loan amount* (e.g. you get a mortgage for $500,000 -- that's the loan amount) and *credit limit* (e.g. you have a credit card that can be maxed to $20,000, which is your credit limit)?

Comment: ***Financial terms***  is the more common way to refer to the expressions you are citing:.http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/definition

Comment: The bank wants to know what you owe other parties before it considers giving you a loan. So it is seeking details of your *liabilities* (I don't think *financial* is necessary). The fact that you might have liabilities other than those listed is not relevant to the description.

Comment: Both "loan amount" and "credit limit" are financial terms as Josh says, but they're not amounts that get added together, so there isn't a collective term for the two of them.

Comment: Financial information? Information on their financial history?

Comment: I would view ongoing child support payments as a financial *obligation* rather than a *liability*, though if behind on required payments that would be a liability. The bank would want to know about such obligations though, because they're directly relevant to your ability to pay back the loan.

Comment: 'Financial details' is a hypernym.

Comment: Can it be 'encumbrance details'?

Answer (score 1):

These are typically termed as *financial instruments*. They are divided into distinct asset classes, and for your particular use case, these are **debt-based financial instruments**.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_instrument):

> Financial instruments are monetary contracts between parties that can be created, traded, modified and settled.

The phrase *Line of credit* can encompass loan amount and credit limit. A consumer will have multiple lines of credit.

Answer (score 0):

Mortgages are a type of loan.

Credit cards are a way of accessing a line of credit extended to you by the bank.

Overdrafts are a facility that allow you to take out a variably sized loan, usually up to an agreed amount.

They are all ways of accruing debt. You could categorise them as "debt accrual methods".